# OpenGL code doesn't display the same thing every time?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, glm-math

When running the program two times, it doesn't display the same result at run time, even though I'm using the same executable.

Here is a bit of context:

I'm programming on a MacAir with Sierra 10.13 and my IDE is Xcode 10.1.

I figured out that my problem is caused by the addition of the transformation Matrix in the vertex shader:

```
// This code is not working
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;

uniform mat4 transformM;

void main() {
    gl_Position = transformM * vec4(position, 1.0);
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

And I load the *transformM* matrix this way (I'm using the GLM library for maths):

```
void LoadMatrix(int location, glm::mat4 matrix) {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, &matrix[0][0]);
}
```

where *location* is:

```
uniformName = "transformM";
location = glGetUniformLocation(_shaderID, uniformName.c_str());
```

(I keeped it simple but you can found the full code here: https://github.com/Cuiyere/Ecosystem)

In fact, I expect my code to render a cube and rotate it, but it didn't shows up like 50% of the time.

I don't understand WHY this issue is happening. I checked my code a hundred times, checked the docs.gl website, compared ThinMatrix's code to mine (even if it written in Java, the overall structure and OpenGL functions remains quite the same), checked OpenGL forums, but as far as I can see, nobody ever had this problem.

I think it's an issue with OpenGL's way to use a vertex shader, but I can't affirm that.

Comment: Just guessing here: perhaps your code contains undefined behaviour (a bug). Perhaps your code depends on external stuff like time, that varies from one run to another.

Comment: How do you initialize a variable of type `glm::mat4`? What value do you pass to `LoadMatrix`? Note, the default constructor of `glm::mat4` doesn't initialize the matrix. You've to use `glm::mat4 m(1.0f)`

Comment: @JesperJuhl Well thanks for the advice, I'll double check that but I can't see any place in my code where I'm currently using the time.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm initializing the transformation matrix in this file: https://github.com/Cuiyere/Ecosystem/blob/master/OpenGL_Project/headers/p_maths.h (in the CreateTransformationMatrix function), I also checked that by printing the transformation matrix at every frame and it seemed to be fine actually.

Comment: @Cuiyere "time" was just one example of things you could possibly depend on - there could be other things. I'm leaning more towards the "undefined behaviour" answer - for example, failure to initialize variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the default constructor of `glm::mat4` doesn't initialize the matrix. Before `void Renderer::CreateProjectionMatrix()` is called in the constructor of `class Render`, `_projectionMatrix` is not initialized.

The method `void Renderer::CreateProjectionMatrix()` does not initialize all the fields of the matrix `_projectionMatrix`. The uninitialized fields in the matrix causes undefined behaviour.

Assign the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) to `_projectionMatrix` at the begin of the function, to ensure that all fields are
initialized:

```
void Renderer::CreateProjectionMatrix() {

    _projectionMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    // [...]
}
```

Or use a constructor to initialize the matrix:

```
Renderer::Renderer (Shaders::StaticShader shader)
    : _projectionMatrix(1.0f)
{
    CreateProjectionMatrix();
    // [...]
}
```

But note, if a method is named `CreateProjectionMatrix`, it should set all the fields of the member `_projectionMatrix`.

---

Further you have to initialize the members `_position`, `_pitch`, `_yaw` and `_roll` of `class Camera` in the constructor:

```
Camera()
  : _position(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
  , _pitch(0.0f)
  , _yaw(0.0f)
  , _roll(0.0f)
{};
```

---

In the method `ShaderProgram::CompileShader` is another issue. The type of the return value of `ShaderProgram::ReadShader` is `std::string`. So `ReadShader( shaderPath ).c_str()` will return a pointer to a temporary object, that is destructed immediately at the end of the assignment statement. The `std::string` object gets destructed and the pointer points nowhere.

Assign the return value of `ShaderProgram::ReadShader` to a local variable and use a pointer to the content of this local variable int the scope of `ShaderProgram::CompileShader`:

```
unsigned int ShaderProgram::CompileShader (unsigned int type, const std::string & shaderPath) {
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);

    std::string code = ReadShader( shaderPath );
    const char* src = code.c_str();

    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);   

    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you I fixed it and checked that in every other routine, but unfortunately that is not what's causing the problem.
In fact, even if I implemented the projection matrix and the view matrix, the issue is that, when using *only* the transformation matrix in the shader (as shown in my first post), the cube is sometimes rendered.
For instance, if I compile my project and run the same executable 5 times, the cube might show only one or two times, and I don't see why there's such a behaviour while "nothing" changed (at least the executable doesn't changed).

Comment: Ok so that last part about the issue in the *ShaderProgram::CompileShader* function was to the problem.
Thank you very much, you teached me something new and now everything is working nicely !